# A sequence tends to negative infinity equivalent to negative sequence tending to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that if the following result is true $(a_{n}) \to - \infty \Leftrightarrow (-a_{n}) \to \infty$

Attempt:

$(a_{n})\to - \infty \Leftrightarrow \forall C < 0, \exists N$ s.t. $a_{n} < C, \forall n > N$ $\tag{1}\label{1}$

Now I obviously need to introduce a negative sign somehow to get to the definition of converging to infinity.

Multiplying $\eqref{1}$ by a negative I get:

$-(a_{n}) = (-a_{n})$ on the RHS and $\forall C > 0, \exists N \text{s.t. } a_{n} > C, \forall n < N$. But now I the last inequality is incorrect...

Comment: I was just multiplying the entire thing by a negative sign so that the inequality's will change direction. But I wasn't sure if it will effect the quantifiers so I just put everything in brackets.

Comment: @Gae.S. I made an edit to the main question.

Comment: Forget about the negative sign for a minute.  What is your definition for $(b_n)\to\infty$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring $(a_{n}) \to \infty$ if, for every $C > 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $a_{n} > C$ for all $n > N$

Comment: Okay, now replace $a_n$ with $-a_n$ wherever it appears on both sides.

Comment: $-(a_{n}) = (-a_{n})$ (LHS).  and if for every $C > 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $-a_{n} > C$ for all $n > N$ (RHS)

Comment: But now I don't see how we can make the $C < 0$ I don't know why i find this so confusing -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show one direction.  You should show the other.  Assume $a_n \to -\infty$.  Therefore, for all $C < 0,$ there is some $N$ such that $a_n < C$ for all $n \geq N.$

To show $-a_n \to \infty,$ we want to show that for all $C > 0,$ there is some $N$ such that $-a_n > C$ for all $n \geq N.$

Therefore, let $C > 0$ be arbitrary.  Therefore $-C < 0,$ so by the assumption that $a_n \to -\infty,$ there is some $N$ (which we now fix) such that $a_n < -C$ for all $n \geq N.$

Let $n \geq N.$  It follows that $a_n < -C$ so $-a_n > C.$

---

As an important point that seemed (at least to me) to be tripping you up:  Note that when we apply the assumption of $a_n \to -\infty,$ we don't need $'C'$ explicitly.  We just need a negative number.  When we assumed $C > 0,$ we obviously get $-C < 0$ so we can then apply the limit definition.

Comment: Thanks I get it now! Yes that was tripping me up.